# My calendar library is not working. What's the issue?

Tags: python-3.x, import, calendar

[This is the screenshot I have taken. Please take a look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrBES.png)

I have started coding recently and having an issue regarding calendar library in Python. I am new to coding and I'm not able to figure this out. How can I fix this. Please help me.

Comment: We can't help you unless you share your calendar library's code

Answer (score 1):

It's because the filename itself is called "calendar.py". Rename your file to something else and see if that works.

When doing an import, it first looks in the current directory, if it doesn't exist then it looks in the python's path (where most of the built in libraries are, which you are trying use).

So when you do `import calendar`and the name of the file itself is `calendar.py`. What you're using is the calendar.py (not the installed library `calendar`). Therefore there will be a `circular import` because the `month` attribute doesn't exist in your `calendar.py`

Answer (score 0):

It considers your python file as a module! Thus, your calendar module doesn't have the month attribute! Change your python file name. It will be okay.